# Typescript not inferring expression signature match

Tags: typescript

I've been playing around with some generic algebraic datatypes in Typescript (v3.5.2 which should be the latest), and it seems to be having trouble detecting a signature match on functions that seems like it should be able to figure out:

```js
  type Success<T> = {          
    tag: 'success';            
    value: T;
    fbind<R, E>(func: (value: T) => Result<R, E>) : Result<R, E>;
  } 

  type Failure<E> = {          
    tag: 'failure';
    error: E;
    fbind<T>(_func: (value: T) => Failure<E>) : Failure<E>;
  }

  type Result<T, E> = Success<T> | Failure<E>;

  function success<T>(value: T) : Success<T> {
    return {
      tag: 'success',
      value,
      fbind<R, E>(func: (value: T) => Result<R, E>): Result<R, E> {
        return func(this.value);
      },
    };
  }

  function failure<E>(error: E) : Failure<E> {
    return {
      tag: 'failure',
      error,
      fbind<T>(_func: (value: T) => Failure<E>) : Failure<E> {
        return this;
      },
    };
  }

  type ValidationError = string;

  function parseDate(value: string) : Result<Date, ValidationError> { 
    // simple example to show issue 
    return success(new Date(value));
  }

  function logDate(date: Date) : Result<Date, ValidationError> {
    console.log('Date: ', date);
    return success(date);
  }

  parseDate('1-1-2019').fbind(logDate);
```

On the `.fbind` call to `logDate`, it is outputting the following error:

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '(<R, E>(func: (value: Date) => Result<R, E>) => Result<R, E>) | (<T, R>(_func: (value: T) => Result<R, string>) => Result<R, string>)' has no compatible call signatures.
```

Is there a mistake somewhere that I am not seeing? Or, is there a way to provide some help to the type system so it can figure it out?

**Update**

With the following code:

```js
type Success<T> = { 
  tag: 'success';
  value: T;
  fbind<R, E>(func: (value: T) => Result<R, E>) : Result<R, E>;
}

type Failure<E> = { 
  tag: 'failure';
  error: E;
  fbind<T, R>(_func: (value: T) => Result<R, E>) : Result<R, E>;
}

type Result<T, E> = Success<T> | Failure<E>;

function success<T>(value: T) : Success<T> { 
  return { 
    tag: 'success',
    value,
    fbind<R, E>(func: (value: T) => Result<R, E>): Result<R, E> { 
      return func(this.value);
    },
  };
}

function failure<E>(error: E) : Failure<E> { 
  return { 
    tag: 'failure',
    error,
    fbind<T, R>(_func: (value: T) => Result<R, E>) : Result<R, E> { 
      return this;
    },
  };
}

type ValidationError = string;

function parseDate(value: string) : Result<Date, ValidationError> { 
  // simple example to show issue
  return success(new Date())
}

function logDate(date: Date) : Result<Date, ValidationError> { 
  console.log('Date: ', date);
  return success(date);
}

parseDate('1-1-2019').fbind(logDate);
```

On the `.fbind` call to `logDate`, it is still outputting the following error:

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '(<R, E>(func: (value: Date) => Result<R, E>) => Result<R, E>) | (<T, R>(_func: (value: T) => Result<R, string>) => Result<R, string>)' has no compatible call signatures.
```

After filing an issue on the typescript repo, it appears that typescript does not currently support calls to unions of multiple generic function signatures in version 3.5.3 and lower (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32314).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you break down the implementation and make it more grandular as follows

```
const result = parseDate('1-1-2019');
if (result.tag === 'success') {
  result.fbind(logDate);
} else if (result.tag === 'failure') {
  result.fbind(logDate);
}
```

you'll get a more specificthe error

```
Argument of type '(date: Date) => Result<Date, string>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Date) => Failure<string>'.
  Type 'Result<Date, string>' is not assignable to type 'Failure<string>'.
    Property 'error' is missing in type 'Success<Date>' but required in type 'Failure<string>'
```

So since `parseDate` is returning either a Success or Failure and both of their implementations of `fbind` take different callbacks, there is a case where if `parseData` returned Failure and we tried to pass `logDate` (which outputs a Success/Failure) into Failures' `fbind` which only accepts a callback that returns `Failure`, so typescript throws an error.

Comment: If I switch Failure to `fbind<T, R>(_func: (value: T) => Result<R, E>) : Result<R, E>;` than the conditional code you posted no longer has errors, but `parseDate(...).fbind(logDate)` still has a `no compatible call signatures` error.